# .NET Core: What does MethodImplOptions.AggressiveOptimization exactly do?

Tags: .net, optimization, .net-core, documentation, jit

What does `MethodImplOptions.AggressiveOptimization` exactly do?
[Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimploptions?view=netcore-3.1) doesn't not tell me much. In which cases can it be useful?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would look for more details info (if that's what's you are looking for) not in the documentation but on [.net core github](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx) or in [release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0).

Let's start by looking at the latter. For .net core 3.0 we can find the following entry:

> The fully optimizing JIT produces higher-quality (or more optimized) code more slowly. For methods where Quick JIT would not be used (for example, if the method is attributed with MethodImplOptions.AggressiveOptimization), the fully optimizing JIT is used.

So for one, we know that if a method is marked with such attribute, it should be JITed with fully optimizing JIT, which might produce better, more optimized code - but would take more time to compile.

Now let's focus on github and see what we can find there.

The discussion about this is done in this [ticket](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/27370), and it gives a bit more details into the topic.

> The flag could be used in a MethodImplAttribute to indicate that the method contains hot code:
>
> - For tiering, it could cause tier 1 JIT to be used right away for the method[...]
> - It could allow the JIT to spend more JIT time to generate better code, such as inlining more aggressively into the function

From this we can get an answer to, in which cases it could be used but also what it is doing underneath.

In cases we deal with hot path code - this attribute is useful to JIT it to produce faster, more optimized code instead of doing tiered compilation. Using more time at the beginning saves time later if runtime detects that it's, in fact, on the hot path.

There's also an interesting discussion about other usages of this flag which you can read.

But the ultimate truth (I hope) and commits are linked to this discussion so we can look at them. And from those commits and commit messages we can get that this is in fact what's happening with tiered compilation and JIT (at least this is what I can see).

Comment: So this flag is only useful for tiered compilation and is doing nothing otherwise?

Comment: This at least what I could find.

Comment: It currently does two things: (1) makes the method ineligible for prejitting and (2) makes the method ineligible for tiered compilation. Net result is that the method is always jitted when first called, and the jitted code is optimized. Use this flag only if you find that running prejitted or Tier0 code for the method causes unwanted effects (either loss of perf, or extra allocations).  If you do not see these unwanted effects you are probably better off not using the flag; regular Tier1 code will often perform better than AggressiveOptimization code.

Comment: @Redhouane you should know what is hot code for you (profiling?). A bit more info how JIT know which methods is a good candidate for better Jitting can be found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/design-docs/tiered-compilation.md).

Comment: @AndyAyers: With "often perform better" you mean load time, or what else could be better?

Comment: The code the jit produces with  normal Tier1 rejitting is often better optimized than the code produces with AggressiveOptimization. The key difference here is when the optimized version of the method is jitted. For normal  Tier1 jitting happens later in the life of the process  and so the jit can better take advantage of already initialized classes -- hence the normal Tier1 jitted code will not need as many class init checks and can incorporate values and types of readonly statics from initialized classes. Methods with AggressiveOptimization are jitted earlier and so lose out here.